# Reoccuring AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Whem I am going to run this code (creating a web scraper to look at company reviews), I am unable to run the loop because the code keeps stopping and saying that I have an Attribute error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'. Not sure why this is happening but would love some clarification and a possible solution if someone is able to answer this query.

```
for i in range(10,140,20):
     url = (f'https://www.indeed.com/cmp/Ey/reviews?fcountry=IT&start={i}')
     header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0 GoogleChrome/10.0'}
     page = requests.get(url,headers = header)
     soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
     results = soup.find('div', { 'id' : 'cmp-container'})
     elems = results.find_all(class_="cmp-Review-container")
```

I can post the rest of the code if needed but the error occus at the elems object. Thanks for the help!

I have tried to circumvent this by looking at the df.head() however I am unable to parse the source code.

Comment: This means the `results` `cmp-container` element could not be found (`find` returns `None` if it can't find what you told it to find).

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

Well, I couldn't do the same with indeed url, so I tried with google (https://www.google.com/)

First of all, to everyone who wanna try to run the code:

```
pip install beautifulsoup
pip install lxml
```

then...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = (f'https://www.google.com/')
header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0 GoogleChrome/10.0'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(page.content), 'lxml')
results = soup.find('div', { 'id' : 'gbwa'})
elems = results.find_all(class_="gb_N")
```

So, if the element you are searching for is empty, or None (doesn't exist in this part), the exception:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

will be thrown

In image attached, you can see some test

[image: Test with google url]

Comment: Yes, I have tested the URL and looked into the source code behind the URL.  Not sure why yours is providing that error. I have also researched Indeed and it allows webscraping

Comment: @RobertBecketI updated my response, please take a look for what I add, and if possible give me a feedback to try some other things. But I think the main problem is related to the element you are searching for, that is empty or doesn't exist

Comment: Not sure why it is returning an empty list though, it should be pulling the reviews from Indeed (in my code) however it is returning blank which is strange. Not sure how to fix this.